# Firebase How to prevent users with non verified email to login?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

With Firebase authentification `signInWithEmailAndPassword`, users can log in even if the email has not been verified.

I don't want users with non verified email to login. I can't find any function like `signInWithVerifiedEmailAndPassword`, so I guess we can't prevent a non verified user to login?

What should I do? Should I check `userCredential.emailVerified` after login and log the user out if `userCredential.emailVerified == false`? That's a bit weird, no ?

Comment: Authentication (the purpose of Firebase Authentication) is a way for the user to prove that their credentials match with what's on file. Nothing more. If you don't want to allow the user access to the app until they've verified their email address, check that property in your application code (both client-side and server-side) before allowing them access. If you have a concern about that, please be specific about that concern.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen OK, I understand, thank you.